# TSQL Query Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have the following data set:

```
ID   PeriodID    Account     Amount  
1    1000        Y0001       100.00  
2    1000        M0001       20.00  
3    1000        Y0002       75.00  
4    1000        M0002       15.00  
5    1000        Y0003       100.00  
6    1000        Y0004       200.00
```

I need to write a query that returns a zero for ever time there is a "Y" account and no "M" account such as:

```
PeriodID    Account     Amount  
1000        Y0001       100.00  
1000        M0001       20.00  
1000        Y0002       75.00  
1000        M0002       15.00  
1000        Y0003       100.00  
1000        Y0003       0.00  
1000        Y0004       200.00 
1000        Y0004       0.00
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the most efficient way, but this should get you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT PeriodID, Account, Amount
FROM myTable

UNION ALL

SELECT PeriodID, Account, 0.00 AS Amount
FROM myTable A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM myTable B 
    WHERE B.Account = 'M' + SUBSTRING(A.Account, 2, LEN(A.Account) - 1)
)
```

Comment: Thanks this was pretty close to doing what I needed. The data I had to work with turned out to be a little different that I had expected. The data also included muliiple dates per periodID, with a single accountID per date.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to do it, assuming account is unique in one period:

```
SELECT m1.PeriodID
    , COALESCE(CASE WHEN at.AccountType = 'Y' then m1.Account end, m2.Account, m1.Account) as Account
    , COALESCE(CASE WHEN at.AccountType = 'Y' then m1.Amount end, m2.Amount, 0.00) as Amount
FROM myTable m1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable m2
        ON m2.PeriodID = m1.PeriodID
        AND m2.ACCOUNT = STUFF(m1.Account, 1, 1, 'M')
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Y' as AccountType UNION ALL SELECT 'M') at
WHERE m1.Account LIKE 'Y%'
ORDER BY m1.PeriodID, m1.Account, at.AccountType DESC
```

Comment: This does not yield the correct results. For example where there should only be one record with 'M0001' and one with 'Y0001' this query produces two records with 'M0001' and none with 'Y0001'

Comment: Change this `COALESCE(m1.Account, m2.account) as Account` to this `STUFF(m1.Account, 1, 1, at.AccountType) as Account`

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I actually had exactly the line you suggest in my first edit, but changed it when I realized the question asks for duplicate Y records. Didn't test it and got it wrong though. Now I have changed it again, and also added an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Using case:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
("ID" int, "PeriodID" int, "Account" varchar(5), "Amount" int);

INSERT INTO Table1
("ID", "PeriodID", "Account", "Amount")
VALUES
(1, 1000, 'Y0001', 100.00),
(2, 1000, 'M0001', 20.00),
(3, 1000, 'Y0002', 75.00),
(4, 1000, 'M0002', 15.00),
(5, 1000, 'Y0003', 100.00),
(6, 1000, 'Y0004', 200.00);
```

The Query:

```
SELECT "PeriodID", "Account",
CASE WHEN Substring("Account",0,2) = 'M'THEN "Amount" ELSE 0.0 END As value
FROM Table1
```